# Is there any way to get device unique code which will not change in web js and android?

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, fingerprint, fingerprintjs2

I want to identify the unqiue visitor in web and android,

So I take attention on the fingerprintjs and fingerprint-android.
But they dont calculate the same code.

How can I achieve that or is it possible to achieve this thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, they generate different fingerprints because they use different APIs for getting signals (which hash is calculated from).
JavaScript FingerprintJS uses signals (eg. from `document.window` object) using the browser's JavaScript API. On the other hand, [fingerprint-android](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprint-android) uses signals (device details, os properties...) from the Android API.

There are some other techniques to get unique identifiers (UUID, IMEI, Mac addresses...) but they got their own significant downsides. You can learn more in [this article](https://fingerprintjs.com/blog/device-fingerprinting-android/).

> How can I achieve that or is it possible to achieve this thing?

TL;DR: AFAIK without cookies/login/some shared identifier it's not possible.

PS: There is also another naive way to use FingerprintJS in the browser and webview. However, the chance of the same hash is pretty low since there are different signals for webview vs browser context.